# Mapping SQL View in EF Core 5 - SaveChanges

Tags: ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to add a view as a Navigation Property of an entity.

```
 public class Schedule
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal ScheduledQuantity { get; set; }
        public ScheduleDetails ScheduleDetails { get; set; }
    }
 public class ScheduleDetails
    {
        public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
        public decimal BadQuantity { get; set; }
        public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
    }
```

with mappings:

```
    public class ScheduleDetailMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ScheduleDetails>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ScheduleDetails> builder)
        {
            builder.ToView("vwScheduleDetails", "ShopOrders");
            builder.HasKey(t => t.ScheduleId);
            builder.HasOne(p => p.Schedule).WithOne(s => s.ScheduleDetails);

        }
    }

    public class ScheduleMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Schedule>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Schedule> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Schedules");
            builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
            builder.Property(t => t.Id).UseIdentityColumn();
        }
    }
```

when I query it works fine.  However if I add a new Schedule record.

```
     var schedule = new Schedule
            {
                ScheduledQuantity = 100,
                ScheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetails()
            };
            context.Schedules.Add(schedule);

            context.SaveChanges();
```

I get an exception saying " The entity type 'ScheduleDetails' is not mapped to a table, therefore the entities cannot be persisted to the database. Use 'ToTable' in 'OnModelCreating' to map it."

Is there anyway to get EF to ignore saving this 'entity'?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an old question, but for anyone having similar issues - in my case the problem lied in navigation properties in my view. I had some leftover properties in view's class, because its code was copied from other entity. By removing those properties, the error was gone.

This doesn't really help if you want to use navigation properties in your code, but it may help someone to continue their search.